# Convert array of time from UTC to ISO format in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js for the time format. SO right now I am getting UTC time(get time from server which is locate other timezone), SO I want to convert into ISO 8601. I am able to convert single value UTC to ISO. But I cant convert whole array into ISO Format.

```
var time= [11:30,11:50,12:50,22:30,23:10,2:20,4:30,8:50,9:10]
```

I want to each value convert into ISO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through you array, parse your input using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and then use [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) or [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Here a live sample:

```js
var time= ['11:30','11:50','12:50','22:30','23:10','2:20','4:30','8:50','9:10'];
var result = time.map(elem => moment.utc(elem, 'HH:mm').toISOString());
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you feel this question is useful for the others user then plz up vote the this question.

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating over the values and replace them?

```
for (i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    time[i] = moment(time[i], 'hh:mm');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()`

```
var time = ["11:30","11:50","12:50","22:30"]
    .map(el => moment(el, 'hh:mm'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map to convert each value:

```
let converted = time.map(t => t.toISOString());
```

t.toISOString() - it's just for example you can add any logic and return converted time.